# Install package from repo not in sources

Tags: package-management, repository

Our machines bootstrap from a Debian repo `repo.foo.com/test trusty`

We need to be able to programatically install a package of a higher version from a separate repo `repo.foo.com/dev trusty` and would ideally like to do this without having to insert lines and them remove them from the sources list as it's a one off.

Is there a facility that will allow something like the following?

`apt-get install updatedApp -repo repo.foo.com/dev trusty`

The repos are private to the network.

Comment: Take a look at this on [AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository)

Comment: @SailorCire apt-preferences require the source to be in sources.list and additionally editing the preferences file.